# Unknown macro in library

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make a library, went well so far, but after adding a few functions it went bad.

When I run the script form the editor it is written in the script works. But when I try to test it the script cannot recognize the server handlers, giving an error: Unknown macro handler_function_name

I checked, all the names in the handlers correspond to names of functions. I read that some people had problems because the code was in different files, moved all the code in the same file the problem is still there.

It does not behave like that for all the handlers...

What else could be the reason for this?

edit:

The app creates additional panels during as a response to "clicks". Handlers of elements on those panels are the ones who's macros (that is handler functions) the app is not able to "find".

How can this be solved?
(except for the solution to put all the panels in the original panel and then change visibility, this works as far as handlers go but raises other problems)

So to put some code here, this is very very simple code...

```
function notWorkingGUI(){

  var app=UiApp.createApplication();
  var appPanel=app.createVerticalPanel().setId("appPanel");
  var handler1=app.createServerHandler("handlerFunction1").addCallbackElement(appPanel);
  var firstButton=app.createButton("Button 1", handler1);

  appPanel.add(firstButton);
  app.add(appPanel);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app);

}

function handlerFunction1(e){

  var app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var appPanel2=app.createVerticalPanel().setId("appPanel2").setStyleAttribute("zIndex", 0).setStyleAttribute("position", "fixed");
  var handler2=app.createServerHandler("handlerFunction2").addCallbackElement(appPanel2);
  var secondButton=app.createButton("Button 2", handler2);
  var label=app.createLabel("This should get visible after the click").setId("label").setVisible(false);

  appPanel2.add(secondButton).add(label);
  app.add(appPanel2);

  return app;


}

function handlerFunction2(e){

  var app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  app.getElementById("label").setVisible(true);

  return app;

}
```

This will work as expected when executed from the editor in which it is written, that is it will show firstButton then secondButton and finaly the label, however if it would be published as a library and invoked from an other script it would only recognise functionHandler1, that is show firstButton, secondButton but after a click on the secondButton an error message will be seen.

However if the script would be written like this:

```
function workingGUI(){

  //previous first part
  var app=UiApp.createApplication();
  var appPanel=app.createVerticalPanel().setId("appPanel");
  var handler1=app.createServerHandler("handlerFunction1a").addCallbackElement(appPanel);
  var firstButton=app.createButton("Button 1", handler1);


  //previous second part
  var appPanel2=app.createVerticalPanel().setId("appPanel2").setStyleAttribute("zIndex", 0).setStyleAttribute("position", "fixed");
  var handler2=app.createServerHandler("handlerFunction2a").addCallbackElement(appPanel2);
  var secondButton=app.createButton("Button 2", handler2).setId("button2");


  appPanel.add(firstButton);
  app.add(appPanel);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app);

}

function handlerFunction1a(e){

  var app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();



  var label=app.createLabel("This should get visible after the click").setId("label").setVisible(false);

  app.getElementById("appPanel2").add(app.getElementById("button2")).add(label);
  app.add(app.getElementById("appPanel2"));

  return app;


}

function handlerFunction2a(e){

  var app=UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  app.getElementById("label").setVisible(true);

  return app;

}
```

Note that all handlers must be defined in the main function, meaning that also all the elements using those handlers and all the callback elements have to be defined here.
Then it would work even as a library, however for some reason this makes the script much much slower even for such a simple example.

Comment: Could you please post the project key for the library, so I can try to include it or otherwise post the code here?

Comment: sorry can't post the code for this library here but I can post similar code (which will create the same problem) or contact me through g+

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1346

It is calling the local code rather than the library code.

I wonder if it is still slow if you add a stub function in the local code?

i.e.

```
function runthis() {
  library.createGUI();
}
function myevent() {
 library.myevent();
}
```

Comment: Solved that issue by putting all the code in one file, it got much much faster. When making my script I divided handlers and their helper functions by what they respond to, basically every button had it's file, after merging all of those it got better.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem, it makes the script a bit slower but if you define all the handlers (that implies all the UI elements) in the original function it will work.